# is shuffle a Monad?

Tags: ct.category-theory, monads

In the list monad, your map $TT \rightarrow T$ takes a list of lists and concatenates them to form a list.  There is another way to take a list of lists and create a list, which is to shuffle randomly the two lists together.  You can also imagine taking a list of lists and mapping that to a set of every shuffle.  I do not think you can create a Monad with this map because there is a number of ways to shuffle two lists.  I guess I want to know if there is a shuffle monad, or how would you model this with functors and natural transformations?  Interestingly, people doing functional programming have done something like this

http://www.drmaciver.com/2008/04/monadic-card-shuffling/

Comment: There exists an operad closely related to the shuffle product, usually called the Zinbiel operad.

Answer (score 2):

The haskell monad you mention models the process of drawing from a sequence at random. It is a state monad--with underlying map of objects $X \mapsto (S\times X)^S$--where the state includes the remaining list of elements and a 'source of randomness'. Every object $S$ of a Cartesian closed category induces a state monad on that category.

Answer (score 0):

[It looks like shuffle may be a quasi monad.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1571066116300779)